# Как TomCat-у указать правильный путь до XML-Файла?

Tags: java, gwt

Приветствую!
В папке **webapp \ WEB-INF** лежит **XML**-Файл с данными для начальной загрузки базы: 
**webapp \ WEB-INF \ orders.xml**

На стороне сервера делаю:

```
final File xmlFile = new File("WEB-INF/orders.xml");
```

Но при запуске приложения получаю от TomCat-а ошибку:

```
D:\apache\Tomcat8024\bin\WEB-INF\orders.xml (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
```

т.е. TomCat ищет XML-ку не в директории приложения\WEB-INF а в bin-папке самого сервера. Понимаю что надо где-то указать путь, но не знаю где.

Comment: getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)

Comment: Спасибо Вам за подсказку, но не совсем понимаю как мне это связать с xmlFile ?

Comment: ну вам же не файл нужен а данные из него =)

Comment: InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/orders.xml")

Comment: Да, именно так и сделал, но в "is" почему то null. Но! Не знаю правильно или нет, но перенёс orders.xml в ветку resources, а строчку кода переделал так:  InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("orders.xml"); и заработало. Но не знаю, считается ли это правильным подходом )

Comment: нормально, но туда и смотрит, или к исходному пути добавьте ./web-inf ,кажется так, я не могу проверить с телефона =)

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Выручили ))